# I want to create a horizontal navigation bar which can have multiple list items

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a navigation bar with multiple list items. Limit number of button on the main view to 6 buttons and the remainder of the pages get placed under "..." menu.

[image: Expected Navigation bar]

I am able to create horizontal bar , I want to know how to limit it to 6 button and place remaining under '...'

I am fetching the data from DB and inside for loop i am creating the buttons in navigation panel. However i want to limit it to 6 button and the other items should be placed under '...'. When we select an item from '...', it should appear on screen. If i get any sample code for this will also be helpful.

Below is the code, not sure if it will be helpful for debug.

```
for (var j = 0; j < memberNavigationList.$values.length; j++) {
                var jitem = memberNavigationList.$values[j];
                var url = integra_tolower(integra_trim(APPPATH + jitem.URL));
                var currenturl = integra_tolower(integra_trim(self.location.href));
                if ((jitem.URL.toLowerCase().indexOf('emr/summary/visitdock') != -1 || jitem.URL.toLowerCase() == 'applications/encounternote.aspx') && jitem.PreviousVisit != '' && jitem.PreviousVisit.length > 10) {
                    sidebar_nav.push('<li id="menuTertairyItemId_' + j + '" style="margin: 0 5px 0 0;"  onmouseover="$ic.tertiaryNav.Showtooltip(this);"  onclick="openVisitFromNavbar(\'')
                    sidebar_nav.push(jitem.PreviousVisit + '$' + jitem.PreviousVisitDate + '$' + EMRContextApplicationId);
                    if (jitem.URL.toLowerCase().indexOf('emr/summary/visitdock') != -1) {
                        sidebar_nav.push('\'' + ',' + '\'' + jitem.URL);
                    }


                    sidebar_nav.push('\');"');
                    sidebar_nav.push('data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="' + jitem.Description + '" class="myTip btn pull-left ic2-flowsheet-btn-gray ' + ' ');

                }  else {
                    if (jitem.Indented === true) {
                        sidebar_nav.push('<li id="menuTertairyItemId_' + j + '" style="margin: 0 5px 0 0;" onclick="$ic.tertiaryNav.menuItemClicked(this,\'' + url + '\',\'' + jitem.URL.toUpperCase() + '\',\'' + jitem.description + '\',\'' + jitem.PageType + '\');" onmouseover="$ic.tertiaryNav.Showtooltip(this)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="' + jitem.Description + '" class="myTip ic2-flowsheet-btn-gray btn pull-left '  + '');
                    } else {

                        sidebar_nav.push('<li id="menuTertairyItemId_' + j + '" style="margin: 0 5px 0 0;" onclick="$ic.tertiaryNav.menuItemClicked(this,\'' + url + '\',\'' + jitem.URL.toUpperCase() + '\',\'' + jitem.description + '\',\'' + jitem.PageType + '\');" onmouseover="$ic.tertiaryNav.Showtooltip(this)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="' + jitem.Description + '" class="myTip ic2-flowsheet-btn-gray btn pull-left ' + '');
                    }
                }

                if (currenturl.indexOf(url) > -1 || (currenturl.match(/addpatientencounter.aspx/g) && url.match(/patientencounters.aspx/g))) {
                    sidebar_nav.push(' ic2-flowsheet-btn-gray-active ');
                } else {
                    if (url.indexOf("popover") > -1) {
                        sidebar_nav.push(' ic2-flowsheet-btn-green ');
                    } else {
                        sidebar_nav.push('  ');
                    }
                }               
               

                sidebar_nav.push('">');
                sidebar_nav.push('<a href="#"></a>'+jitem.Description);
                sidebar_nav.push('</li>');
            }
        }
        
        

        sidebar_nav.push('</ul>'); // close the sidebarnav
```

Comment: Here we go, I've done it for you: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A16o.png I also testet in multiple browsers and it works fine. <ironieoff> you should show your code!

Comment: [How TO - More Button in Navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_more_button.asp) 
The rest is magic

Answer (score 0):

this is an example it will help you ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```